# Suggestions for rate limiting using Axios

Tags: reactjs, settimeout, axios, es6-promise

I'm using react with axios for accessing api from cryptocompare. Api has limit of 15 call per second.

Now after 15 api call I'm getting error of "Rate limit exceeded".

I am looking for a library which can help set the rate limiting options for the axios call.

Comment: You could use lodash.throttle function https://lodash.com/docs/4.17.10#throttle to rate limit your call.

Comment: Or use RxJs's debounce. Here is a [tutorial](https://medium.com/aviabird/rxjs-reducing-number-of-api-calls-to-your-server-using-debouncetime-d71c209a4613) I found

Answer (score 0):

have you followed best practices to fetch data in react ? https://blog.hellojs.org/fetching-api-data-with-react-js-460fe8bbf8f2
you need to fetch only once in componentWillMount and keep it into state